# MVC WebApi not reading cloud configs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, config

I have a MVC WebApi running on a web role.  It works just fine with one exception: it can't read anything from the service configs.  I have a web role that is mapped to the project.  But when I build and call

```
CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ImportantKey")
```

it just shows

```
Getting "ImportantKey" from Serviceruntime: FAIL.
Getting "ImportantKey" from ConfigurationManager: FAIL.
```

yet in the service config, I can cleary see

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="ImportantKey" value="1234abcd" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

I have an MVC web role that does the same thing and it all works just fine.  What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: if I use RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("ImportantKey") it works just fine.  What do I have configured incorrectly for CloudConfigurationManager?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  When you right click on a reference in Visual Studio and select Properties, it may or may not show you the actual specific version it's using.  In both cases (MVC web role or Web API web role) it said the version for Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration was 3.0.0 but when I opened up the packages config, it was actually using 3.2.1 in one of the cases.  I updated the other to match and everything works now.